# 'No generic method > 'OrderByDescending' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I'm trying to dynamically use reflection to do an `OrderBy` on whether a given `sortColumn` (string) is null or not, a `ThenBy` on the `sortColumn` value, and a `ThenBy` on hard-coded columns. Like so:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn)) {
    var descending = sortDirection == "desc";
    views = views.AsQueryable()
        .OrderByNull<ToDoView>(sortColumn, true)  // extension method
        .OrderBy<ToDoView>(sortColumn, descending, true)  // extension method
        .ThenBy(v => v.summary ?? v.description).ToList();
}
```

Using other SO answers, I was able to get the `OrderBy` extension method to work:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
        string orderByProperty, bool desc, bool thenBy = false) {
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    if (thenBy)
        command = desc ? "ThenByDescending" : "ThenBy";
    var type = typeof(TEntity);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var resultExpression =  Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        command, 
        new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        source.Expression, 
        Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

Here is my `OrderByNull` extension method:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderByNull<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
        string orderByProperty, bool desc, bool thenBy = false) {
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    if (thenBy)
        command = desc ? "ThenByDescending" : "ThenBy";
    var type = typeof(TEntity);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var target = Expression.Constant(null, type);
    var equalsMethod = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameter, orderByProperty), "Equals", null, target);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(equalsMethod, parameter);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        command, 
        new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        source.Expression, 
        Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

When executing this extension method, the `orderByExpression` evaluates to:

```
{p => p.listName.Equals(null)}
```

However, when trying to set the `resultExpression`,  it throws an exception:

> `System.InvalidOperationException`: 'No generic method '`OrderByDescending`' on type '`System.Linq.Queryable`' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.'

I'm not really sure how to fix this, as the expression looks right to me. Any ideas?

---

Here is my final `OrderByNull` extension method, after the fix from the accepted answer and resolving a `NullReferenceException` with the equals logic:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderByNull<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
        string orderByProperty, bool desc, bool thenBy = false) {
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    if (thenBy)
        command = desc ? "ThenByDescending" : "ThenBy";
    var type = typeof(TEntity);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var target = Expression.Constant(null, type);
    var equalsMethod = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, orderByProperty), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(equalsMethod, parameter);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        command, 
        new Type[] { type, typeof(bool) },
        source.Expression, 
        Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

Comment: The result type of your expression is `bool`, not `property.PropertyType`. (I'm skeptical this is translatable by the provider, by the way -- you probably need to use `Expression.Equal` and not a call to `Equals`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the failing case you are specifying `property.PropertyType` (`new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }`) as a `TKey` generic type argument of the called generic method `OrderBy<TSource, TKey>`, but the selector lambda result type (which should match the `TKey`) is `bool`, hence the exception.

To fix it, change

```
new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }
```

to

```
new Type[] { type, typeof(bool) }
```

or more generically (can be used in both methods)

```
new Type[] { type, orderByExpression.ReturnType  }
```